# How Can I replace default Splash Screen in Electron.js package created by Electron Forge

Tags: node.js, electron, splash-screen, electron-packager, electron-forge

Please I am Working on Project **electron**
I need to generate **.exe using Electron Forge make cli**

***it is working but it showing default splash screen
attached below :***

[image]

any one can help me How to re-place this splash screen with mine
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's coming from Squirrel which is the default Windows installer that electron-forge uses to package your app in when you do `npm run make`. There's a Squirrel option you can specify in your forge config to change the splash called `loadingGif`. Here's the full list of Squirrel options:

https://js.electronforge.io/interfaces/_electron_forge_maker_squirrel.InternalOptions.Options.html

Here's a page with example Squirrel configs in the forge config:

https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/squirrel.windows